# How to remove leading and trailing spaces from a string?

Tags: python, string

I'm having a hard time trying to use `.strip` with the following line of code:

```
f.write(re.split("Tech ID:|Name:|Account #:",line)[-1])
```

Comment: What is line? An example would be great or we are just guessing.

Comment: f.write(str(re.split("Tech ID:|Name:|Account #:",line)[-1]).strip)

Comment: From the code you just posted it looks like you forgot the paranthesis  after strip

Comment: You missed the function call parentheses after `strip`. You want: `f.write(str(re.split("Tech ID:|Name:|Account #:",line)[-1]).strip())`.

Comment: Basically I need to write that line without whitespace, trailing spaces ect.

Comment: If you need to `.strip()` the result of `re.split()` (i.e. more strings), you want to strip all the substrings separately.

Comment: If you wanna stip all whitespace you can just call `x.replace(' ','')`

Comment: @jamylak: Not quite *all* whitespace. You need `s/[ \t\r\n]//` at a minimum. ;)

Comment: right, to clarify i just meant normal spaces

Comment: Why don't you just add whitespaces to your regular expression: `re.split(r"\s*(?:Tech ID:|Name:|Account #:)\s*` etc.

Answer (score 303, accepted):

You can use the [`strip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=strip#str.strip) method to remove trailing and leading spaces:

```
>>> s = '   abd cde   '
>>> s.strip()
'abd cde'
```

Note: the internal spaces are preserved.

Comment: Don't forget to assign the output of s.strip() back to s if that's your goal: s=s.strip()

Comment: @GregSchmit How could anyone miss that? 78 likes and no one noticed? Strange.

Comment: @MYGz Yeah, I was even questioning myself, thinking that I might have missed something.

Comment: @GregSchmit Apparently 89294 eyes scanned it. You got 1 sharp pair :P

Comment: Clearly, I am doing something wrong, but I don't know what that is.  When I run strip() on a string, I get back a list of strings, not a string.

Comment: @user1928764 Is it a string to begin with?

Comment: @user1928764 probably using split not strip

Answer (score 5):

Expand your one liner into multiple lines. Then it becomes easy:

```
f.write(re.split("Tech ID:|Name:|Account #:",line)[-1])

parts = re.split("Tech ID:|Name:|Account #:",line)
wanted_part = parts[-1]
wanted_part_stripped = wanted_part.strip()
f.write(wanted_part_stripped)
```

Answer (score 4):

Should be noted that `strip()` method would trim any leading and trailing whitespace characters from the string (if there is no passed-in argument). If you want to trim space character(s), while keeping the others (like newline), this answer might be helpful:

```
sample = '  some string\n'
sample_modified = sample.strip(' ')

print(sample_modified)  # will print 'some string\n'
```

`strip([chars])`: You can pass in optional characters to `strip([chars])` method. Python will look for occurrences of these characters and trim the given string accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Starting file:

```
     line 1
   line 2
line 3  
      line 4
```

Code:

```
with open("filename.txt", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        stripped = line.strip()
        print(stripped)
```

Output:

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
```