# Removing trailing spaces from strings in a list Python

Tags: python, string, list, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am webscraping descriptions under images from a website and I am currently trying to scrape the descriptions using BeautifulSoup.

But that is working, some of the descriptions have one or more trailing spaces that I want to get rid of. How do I check if a string in a list has any trailing spaces and then to get rid of all the trailing spaces in each string of the list?

Comment: You can use `rstrip()` method. You can read more about it here  - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-string-rstrip/

Comment: Or even `rstrip()` if they're trailing

Comment: or `strip()` is you want to remove both leading and trailing whitespace

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove leading and trailing spaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10443400/remove-leading-and-trailing-spaces) or even better: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232953/python-removing-spaces-from-list-objects

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: Removing spaces from list objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232953/python-removing-spaces-from-list-objects)

Comment: Googling your exact title will give many results and many good, relevant answers. Did you even try that before asking here?

Comment: To the last comments posted, I did search it and i just wanted to get a better explanation for my case. My apologies for creating a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
stripped_list = [element.rstrip() for element in original_list]
```